# How to remotely change audio volume on Ubuntu Touch device?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, pulseaudio

How can I remotely change the audio volume of my Ubuntu Touch device?

Comment: OK, someone edited it incorrectly, assuming you typoed "USB ports" which was of course a wrong assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having connected to your device using ssh, give:

```bsh
pactl set-sink-volume 0 <percentage> # (for example "-50%")
```